# I want to export my music library from Noise

Tags: system-installation, software-installation, music

I'm getting a new computer that I'm planning on putting elementary on. I would like to export my Music (Noise) library to the new computer and keep it organized just as it is.

Here's the issue: I reorganized my music using Noise, and it took hours going through several backups, deleting duplicates, updating track names and tags, etc.

I checked "Keep Music folder organized" and "Copy tracks to Music folder." However, in Noise, it says my music is 11.2 GB, but the properties of the Music folder (~/Music) say it's 24.5 GB.

That means there are duplicates still in the Music folder that have been removed from the library by me. I don't care about those files. I don't want to import them again and have to go back through and rework the library again on the new machine, I just want to export the library AS IS and import it into the new machine. Any thoughts on how best to do this?

Thanks!!!